# how can i display a listview on the top of another activity in Android

Tags: android

i am having a custom list view screen and another activity screen but now i want to display the custom list view screen is on top of the another activity ..

thanks for help...

Comment: @user556163: Please consider writing a few hundred more words explaining what it is you are trying to accomplish. What is "on top of the another activity", for example?

Comment: Don't ask the same question over and over, you can edit this one to add details.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should firstly really specify what you really expect as Commons Guy said.

But according to me you can set theme Translucent to achieve that.

Heres a sample in your manifest specify `android:style/Theme.Translucent`

```
<!-- Your Custom ListActivity  -->
<activity android:name=".CustomListVIew"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
```

now if you want to blur the background, before calling setContentView() from you Custom ListView

```
public class CustomListActivity extends ListActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//NO NEED TO CALL BELOW METHOD IF YOU DON'T WANT BLUR
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
}
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Now call you CustomListActivity from your another Activity in onCreate() by

```
statActivity(new Intent(AcivityA.this,CustomListActivity.class));
```

Comment: thank you ..actually here in my project i am having a screen and when we are in that screen we have a menu option in that if we select index option means the custom list view i.e the data of the .xml will come line by line...now what i want is if i press that index option means the current screen will run normally and on that half of the screen will cover with this custom list...i tried this answer but i am getting full screen of the custom list view i can't able to view the current running screen ....can u pls help me

Comment: Well, I really didn't get the scenario correctly. Do you mean you want two activities running side by side on the screen ? Can you add some screenshots ?

Comment: I guess user-chinni is looking for a floating list view.