# custom listview over an exsisting activity

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i display a listview on the top of another activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547511/how-can-i-display-a-listview-on-the-top-of-another-activity-in-android)

hi..i want to display a custom list view  on one existing activity so that the custom list view will cover half screen of the existing activity without interrupting the actions of the existing activity...how can i do that..can any one pls help me
thanks for help.