# dispaly a listview over other activity

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [custom listview over an exsisting activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554770/custom-listview-over-an-exsisting-activity)
>   [how can i display a listview on the top of another activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547511/how-can-i-display-a-listview-on-the-top-of-another-activity-in-android)

i am having 2different activities ..one is main screen in that a menu option is there if i clicked on index means the other custom list activity will be displayed in another screen ..now i want to display that custom list view activity is placed over the main activity and it covers only half of that main activity and the man activity functioning should be normal..how can i do this ...help me to resolve it..

Thanks for help..

Comment: Do you want the main activity to be interactive while the other activity is showing?

Comment: You've asked the same question three times now in a 24 hour period. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554770/custom-listview-over-an-exsisting-activity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547511/how-can-i-display-a-listview-on-the-top-of-another-activity-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are searching for is called drop-down-list.

You can always use the Android Spinner class - http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html